# jQuery sum of total time in input fields 24 hour format

Tags: php, jquery

I'm needing jQuery to automatically give me the sum of the time in the input fields. I tried this but I can't get it to work for 24 hour times

```js
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```css
input {display: block;}
input.total {margin-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text"  value="1:45" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text"  value="1:45" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text"  value="1:45" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text"  value="1:45" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text"  value="1:45" class="qty1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Comment: Please provide any code that you attempted and we can help out from there

Comment: please review my code https://jsfiddle.net/2wwqghwt/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using moment.js;
 https://momentjs.com/

This provides an easy way to manipulate Date() objects.

Id go about this by having some common start date and then use moment.js to add() the hours and minutes.

When all input fields are added, I'd get the difference between the original date and the result via moment.js' diff() function